# How to build ArcGIS Flex Viewer app for remote server?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I'm trying to help a co-worker set up an ArcFlex Viewer app using the Application Builder. I'm a bit puzzled by the settings screen:

[image]

It's asking for a web server base folder (local path) and a web server base folder URL (web path). What should I enter for the local path if this is going to be hosted on a remote server? It's a free hosting service, so I don't really have access to the local path there other than `.../my_user_name/public_html`.

Comment: According to me you need to put that service name or IP. Check similar tutorial regarding this https://www.e-education.psu.edu/cloudGIS/node/42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a web server that you have write access to, in order to create (and view) apps using the application builder.

When you're happy with your application you can move it to the remote server.  All you have to do is move the whole folder.

Say for example you created an application called GreatApp, then (assuming default set up on Windows machine), you can just copy the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\flexviewers\GreatApp folder to your remote server.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the base folder path is for development and the base folder URL is for production?

Comment: No, both are for the same environment. The folder path is where the application builder writes to, and the URL is to be able to view it inside the application builder (in the Preview tab).

Comment: What if this is a Linux server and I'm not able to run the app builder from the server itself? I can't just build an app with the right relative paths and upload to the server?

Comment: The application builder require a web server that you have read/write access to.  See system requirements at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/System_requirements/01m30000002t000000/

Comment: You would either need to start/use a web server on the same machine as the application builder, OR map a drive to the machine that has the web server.

Comment: I appreciate your help Bjorn but I'm still a bit confused - I do have read/write access to this web server via FTP, but it doesn't sound like that is the intended workflow. I also don't understand how mapping a drive to the server is any different from building the app locally and uploading it to the server. But I will play around with it some more and see where I get.

Comment: Read/write to the file system of the web server (not ftp).  The application builder creates files on the file system and then verifies that the URL matches. Building the app locally and then manually uploading it to the server is different from map-the-drive because you have that manual step of uploading.  Of course, without the (direct) web server access, you won't even be able to build the app locally.  Not sure if that helps...